# Reference: semigroups theory for PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to study semigroup theory that people use in PDEs. Can someone recommend a good book/lecture notes that I can use to teach me the basics (and also go into depths) in an accessible way?
Thanks.

Evans has a small section which I don't like to read and I am already aware of Rogers and Renardy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [*Semigroups of Linear Operators and Applications to Partial Differential Equations*](http://books.google.ca/books/about/Semigroups_of_Linear_Operators_and_Appli.html?id=sIAyOgM4R3kC&redir_esc=y) by A. Pazy.

Answer (score 0):

For a short introduction, there is a chapter on Yille-Yosida in the book by Brezis "Functional analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations"